# Refresh just home page

Tags: javascript, refresh

I am currently designing a system which includes a homepage that show the person who logs in only the work they have to do. I have been asked to set up this homepage to refresh every 3 minutes which I have done using this code:

```
function startTimer() {
 var now = new Date();
 var minutes = now.getMinutes();
 var seconds = now.getSeconds();
 var secTime = minutes*60*seconds;

 if(secTime % (3*60) == 0){
  var refreshTime = 3*60*1000;

 } else {
  var refreshTime = (secTime % (3*60))  * 1000;
 }
setTimeout('refresh()', refreshTime);}

function refresh() {
 window.location.href = 'myURL';

}

startTimer();
```

The problem I currently have is that when I navigate away from this page, but still in the system, it keeps returning me to homepage and I lose what I am working on. 
Is there a way that I can keep refreshing homepage for those who haven't moved away from it and stop it when someone does?

I am very new to Javascript so please be patient if I ask a lot of question. 
Thank you in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a shared javascript file on all pages of the site which is why the timer will keep running on every page. You could make sure that the timer only runs on the homepage by checking the page url and wrap your `startTimer` function inside this check:

```
if (document.location.href == "http://www.yourhomepage.com"){
    startTimer();
}
```

Replace http://www.yourhomepage.com with whatever url your homepage is on. This will only work if your pages are separate html files. If you are using a hashbang method whereby the document doesn't change, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to refresh the work log part of the page instead of refreshing the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh your page, your code redirect you to your home page because of `window.location.href = 'myURL';`. The location change, and it redirect you everytime to 'myURL'.

You would like to refresh only a part of your page. You have to send a XMLHttpRequest or Ajax request ( you load a page into your current page without reloading your current page ). https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XMLHttpRequest

When you get the page loaded, you insert the text loaded into the page.

Then, call the function which send request, every "refreshTime" like that

```
function sendAjax(){
 // ... ajax request
 // refreshTime = 3 * 60 * 1000; 
 setTimeout( sendAjax, refreshTime );
}

sendAjax();
```

Don't use quote arround the function name in setTimout. setTimemout need a function to call (not his name but his value) and time parameters.